# Does the order, lattice of subgroups, and lattice of factor groups, uniquely determine a group up to isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lattice-orders

If we have a two lattices (partially ordered) - one for subgroups, one for factor groups, and we know order of the group we want to have these subgroup and factor group lattices, is such a group unique up to isomorphism (if exists)? Or is there a counterexample?

If that's true, are sufficient conditions on the order and subgroup lattices to guarantee uniqueness? Another way - what if we now lattice for subgroup and group of automorphism of group; is that group uniquely determined by that information?

Thanks for help. (sorry for English)

Comment: @tomas.lang: Are you *really* asking the subgroup and factor group lattices to be *totally ordered*? Or just partially ordered? Because there are very few groups with totally ordered subgroup lattices, and in the finite case, they *must* be cyclic.

Comment: @tomas.lang: this might be relevant: http://www.jstor.org/stable/1990375

Comment: @Arturo Migdin: Oh - partially ordered, mistake :-) Thanks for link...

Comment: You really are just looking for groups that have isomorphic subgroup lattice, isomorphic *normal* subgroup lattice, and same order. If I had to guess, I would guess that you will find examples of nonisomorphic groups with the same order and isomorphic lattices among the $p$-groups, just because these kinds of invariants almost always seem to not suffice to distinguish $p$-groups; same for replacing the lattice of normal subgroups with the automorphism group. Perhaps someone can check with GAP for some small exponents.

Comment: I am curious if SmallGroup(243,8) and SmallGroup(243,9) work.  There is a block of 36 hard to distinguish elements in each subgroup lattice, and I cannot tell if they can be mapped to each other.

Comment: #8 and #9 definitely don't work.  There are still few left of order 243 to check.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> **No**, the lattice of subgroups, the lattice of normal subgroups, the order of the group, and the automorphism group do not (even taken together) determine the isomorphism type of a finite group.

Take $G = \mathrm{SmallGroup}(243, 19)$ and $H = \mathrm{SmallGroup}(243, 20)$.  There is a bijection $f \colon L(G) \to L(H)$ between their lattices of subgroups such that:

- $|X| = |f(X)|$,
- $X ≅ f(X)$ unless $X = G$,
- $X ≤ Y$ iff $f(X) ≤ f(Y)$,
- $X ⊴ G$ iff $f(X) ⊴ f(G) = H$,
- $G/X ≅ H/f(X)$ whenever $X ≠ 1$ is normal.

Additionally, $\operatorname{Aut}(G) ≅ \operatorname{Aut}(H)$. The fourth bullet shows in particular, that $f$ induces an isomorphism between the lattice of quotient groups of $G$ and the lattice of quotient groups of $H$. The second and fifth bullets show the isomorphism respects everything about the subgroups’ properties as abstract groups.

The groups $G$ and $H$ have presentations

\begin{align*}
 G &= \bigl\langle a, b, c \mid a^{27} = b^3 = c^3 = 1,\ ba = abc,\ ca = acz,\ cb = bcz \bigr\rangle\text{ where $z = a^9$} \,, \\
H &= \bigl\langle a, b, c \mid a^{27} = b^3 = c^3 = 1,\ ba = abc,\ ca = acz,\ cb = bcz \bigr\rangle\text{ where $z = a^{-9}$} \,.
\end{align*}

The function $f$ is induced by a bijection of the underlying sets:

- $f(a^i b^j c^k) = a^i b^j c^k$.

There are no such groups of order dividing $64$ (even just having an isomorphism of subgroup lattices respecting normal subgroups).

Comment: Thanks for doing the legwork! I'm glad to know my intuition was right and that counterexamples would be found among $p$-groups.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the SmallGroup terminology. Can you point me to a source where it is introduced?

Comment: @Andres Caicedo: They are the nomenclature of GAP's "SmallGroup" library. http://www.gap-system.org/Gap3/Datalib3/small.html; http://www-public.tu-bs.de:8080/~hubesche/small.html

Comment: I added some less computer dependent details.  You can see how G and H are basically identical, and since the lattice isomorphism preserves group orders, it is induced by a bijection of the underlying sets of group elements.  I gave presentations where this bijection is the "obvious" one.