# Must two groups with all subgroups of the same order be isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

Let $G,H$ be finite groups such that there's bijection $\varphi$ from the subgroups of $G$ into the subgroups of $H$ satisfying:

1. $|g_1|=|\varphi(g_1)|$;
2. $g_1 < g_2$ if and only if $\varphi(g_1)<\varphi(g_2)$;
3. $g_1 \triangleleft g_2$ if and only if $\varphi(g_1)\triangleleft\varphi(g_2)$.

Is it always true that $G\cong H$?

This question arises if you consider two Galois extensions $F_1, F_2$ of $K$. If all intermediate extensions $K\subseteq E_1\subseteq F_1$ and $K\subseteq E_2\subseteq F_2$ look the same as $K$-vector fields then $gal(F_1 |K)\cong gal(F_2|K)$?

Comment: Without 3, the answer is [definitely no](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35455/does-the-hypergraph-structure-of-the-set-of-subgroups-of-a-finite-group-characte). I'm pretty sure the answer remains "no" even if we add 3.

Comment: No, I am, sorry! Still, it's worth checking if the order-$16$ example still works here.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14732/742) is another example. It satisfies the stronger condition that corresponding proper subgroups are isomorphic, and the normal subgroups map to normal subgroups.  But I am not sure it satisfies 3, either.

Comment: @MishaLavrov According to the link in my other comment, there shouldn't be counterexamples of order dividing 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jack Schmidt posted [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14732/883143) saying that the two groups of order 243,
$G = \mathrm{SmallGroup}(243, 19)$ and $H = \mathrm{SmallGroup}(243, 20)$ in the [GAP small groups library](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14732/883143) satisfy these conditions and are not isomorphic.